# Gnuplot: how to get better symbol alpha in pdf terminal

Tags: gnuplot, alpha, symbols

Here is the test code:

```
set terminal pdf enhanced;
set output "test.pdf"
plot 1 title "{/Symbol a} {/Symbol b} {/Symbol c}";
```

That gives:

[image]

The alpha produced is very strange. I want a normal alpha like this:

[image]

Is there anyway I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try copy-pasting in the unicode alpha character to your script, and adjust the font to whatever you like:

```
set terminal pdfcairo enhanced font "Arial,14"
set output "test.pdf"
set key font "Times,14"
plot -x title "α β γ"
```

The Symbol font is just another font, and the "strange" alpha is just how it looks in that font.